# why does this test not return False when testing an integer

Tags: python, testing, floating-point

Expect to get this to return False as the string contains an integer

```
def is_float(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

list1 =[['a','4'],['20.1','4'],['100','4'],['102','10'],['31.3','10'],['c','10'],['113','12'],['s','12'],['32.9','12']]
print(is_float(list1[6][0]))
```

This returns true when the value is 113. I would expect a False as the number is an integer?

Comment: Because you've programmed it so it returns `True` if the string can be turned into a `float`?

Comment: Because the 6th element is ['113', '12']. You're probably thinking it's ['c', '10'], but remember that lists are zero-based.

Comment: `float('113')` doesn't raise an exception. There is no reason it should, since `'113'` _can_ be easily converted to a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is python is implicitly concatenating your string of "113" to a float, which doesn't give an error and therefore breaks your is_float method.

What you should be using is the `isinstace()` method which will allow you to test by running `isinstance(variable, type)` and will return a boolean value

Here is how you could implement it:

```py
def is_float(input):
    if isinstance(input, float):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: thanks, i read somewhere this was a test of a float, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

`float()` doesn't check if a variable is of type float, it returns whatever integer (or string) you pass it in the form of a float.  Therefore your function will always return true.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the variable is digit using `isdigit()`.

Along with `isinstance(float(s), float)` that converts the `str` to `float` and then check if it is a `float`:

```
def is_float(s):

    try:
        print(s)
        if s.isdigit():
            return "It is an Integer.", False
        if isinstance(float(s), float):
                return "It is a Float.", False
    except ValueError:
        return "Not an Integer or Float.", True

list1 =[['a','4'],['20.1','4'],['100','4'],['102','10'],['31.3','10'],['c','10'],['113','12'],['s','12'],['32.9','12']]
print(is_float(list1[0][0]))   # a
print(is_float(list1[6][0]))   # 113
print(is_float(list1[8][0]))   # 32.9
```

OUTPUT:

```
a
('Not an Integer or Float.', True)
113
('It is an Integer.', False)
32.9
('It is a Float.', False)
```

Comment: Thanks thats what i am looking for, I want to reject alphas and numeric ...only true to floats. This can do that by the looks of it with slight change

Comment: @Lucullus Perfect, you may accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark beside it if it helped, cheers!

Comment: @user5173426: using `.isdigit` alone is not sufficient if you allows integers lesser than `0`, for example `'-12'.isdigit()` give `False`, when `int('-12')` gives `-12`.

Comment: @Daweo agreed. I only considered the given set of data.

Comment: yep that was great, changed False to True on isinstance and true to false on except return, did job perfectly

Comment: @Lucullus sounds great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others `'113'` could be converted to `float` and will give `113.0`, I want to add it is better to use `try-except-else` in that case instead of `try-except`, i.e.

```
def is_float(s):
    try:
        float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Which should be understanded as try convert to float, if `ValueError` appears return `False`, else return `True`. It will give same result like your original implementation, but note it is more readable, as putting `return True` in `try` block might suggest that you are excepting error from `return` statement.